# How do i make Custom Cell as RoundRect Shape

Tags: iphone

I have a problem with Custom Cell.

I have added a Custom Cell in header view of table. I want to make Something same like in iPhone Contact Application, When you Click Edit or + button.

Custom cell added Successfully but it Shows in Rectangle, rather than in form of Round Rect Shape.

So need your help. Please Let me know the Solution.

Looking forwards.

Thank YOu,

Arun Thakkar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the Grouped UITableView style.
You can set the style of the table view in interface builder very easily.
If you are trying to do it programmatically you can set the `style` property to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`